# Apply condition on particular columns

Tags: pandas

I have an input dataframe that has 7 columns and more than 800k rows.
I need to apply filters only for the columns `ID` and `Band`:

```
    ID      Band    
|--------|-------|
    A11     1800  
    A18     1800  
    B11     1800  
    B18     1800  
    B21     2400
    C11     1800 
    C18     1800  
    2       2100    
    3       2100        
    A1      2100        
    A2      2100
    A16     2300
    A11     1800        
    A18     1800        
    A26     2600        
    A27     2600 
    9       800
```

I need output as

```
  ID        Band
|--------|--------| 
 A11,A18    1800  
 B11,B18    1800 
 B21        2400
 C11,C18    1800  
 2          2100        
 3          2100    
 A1,A2      2100
 A16        2300 
 A11,A18    1800  
 A26,A27    2600 
 9          800
```

Here I combine `ID` values if the `Band` has same values with conditions as follows.

I am checking row by row if same values found in `Band` column, then I check `ID` column if it has numbers I do not touch that entire row.

For alphabets I group them as A values separately, B values separately, C values separately ...etc, so I can get the data for same `Band` column values in my dataframe that has 7 columns and more than 800k rows

How can I achieve this in pandas?

My code is

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
a = pd.read_csv('MasterCellData.csv', encoding= 'unicode_escape', usecols=['antenna types per SDOS', 'Site_ID', 'ID'])
b = pd.read_excel('mapping.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
c = pd.read_excel('mapping.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet2')

a = a.dropna(subset=['antenna types per SDOS'])
a['Mapped'] = a['ID'].map(b.set_index('SECTOR CODE')['Operator'])
a['Tech'] = a['ID'].map(b.set_index('SECTOR CODE')['Supported Tech'])
a['Band'] = a['ID'].map(b.set_index('SECTOR CODE')['BAND DESCRIPTION'])
a['Mapped1'] = a['ID'].map(c.set_index('SECTOR CODE')['Operator'])
a['Tech1'] = a['ID'].map(c.set_index('SECTOR CODE')['Supported Tech'])

# Removing duplicate columns
a['Mapped'] = a['Mapped'].fillna(a.pop('Mapped1'))
a['Tech'] = a['Tech'].fillna(a.pop('Tech1'))

# Assigning value to 3G
a['Band'] = a.apply(lambda row: '1800' if str(row['ID']).isdigit() and pd.isnull(row['Band']) else row['Band'], axis=1)
a['Band'] = a.apply(lambda row: '2100' if row['Tech'] == '3G' and pd.isna(row['Band']) else row['Band'], axis=1)


a['Band'] = a['Band'].apply(lambda x: re.findall(r'\d+', str(x)))
a['Band'] = a['Band'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x) if len(x) > 0 else '')

from string import ascii_uppercase
mapper = {l: i for i,l in enumerate(ascii_uppercase)}
grp1 = a["ID"].str.isnumeric().cumsum() # sequence of alphanum/numbers
grp2 = a["ID"].str[0].map(mapper)       # sequence of letters A, B, ..
out = (
    a.groupby(["Band", grp1, grp2],
               dropna=False, as_index=False, sort=False)["ID"]
        .agg(",".join)[a.columns]
)
out
```

And error I get is:

```
C:\Users\guest\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_9660\1921483541.py:4: DtypeWarning: Columns (16) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
a = pd.read_csv('MasterCellData.csv', encoding= 'unicode_escape', usecols=['antenna types per SDOS', 'Site_ID', 'ID'])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[12], line 33
     30 grp1 = a["ID"].str.isnumeric().cumsum() # sequence of alphanum/numbers
     31 grp2 = a["ID"].str[0].map(mapper)       # sequence of letters A, B, ..
     32 out = (
---> 33     a.groupby(["Band", grp1, grp2],
     34                dropna=False, as_index=False, sort=False)["ID"]
     35         .agg(",".join)[a.columns]
     36 )
     37 out

File ~\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:3767, in DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
   3765     if is_iterator(key):
   3766         key = list(key)
-> 3767     indexer = self.columns._get_indexer_strict(key, "columns")[1]
   3769 # take() does not accept boolean indexers
   3770 if getattr(indexer, "dtype", None) == bool:

File ~\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:5876, in Index._get_indexer_strict(self, key, axis_name)
   5873 else:
   5874     keyarr, indexer, new_indexer = self._reindex_non_unique(keyarr)
-> 5876 self._raise_if_missing(keyarr, indexer, axis_name)
   5878 keyarr = self.take(indexer)
   5879 if isinstance(key, Index):
   5880     # GH 42790 - Preserve name from an Index

File ~\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:5938, in Index._raise_if_missing(self, key, indexer, axis_name)
   5935     raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
   5937 not_found = list(ensure_index(key)[missing_mask.nonzero()[0]].unique())
-> 5938 raise KeyError(f"{not_found} not in index")

KeyError: "['antenna types per SDOS', 'Site_ID', 'Mapped', 'Tech'] not in index"
out.to_csv('DDout')
``´
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option :

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

mapper = {l: i for i,l in enumerate(ascii_uppercase)}

grp1 = df["ID"].str.isnumeric().cumsum() # sequence of alphanum/numbers
grp2 = df["ID"].str[0].map(mapper)       # sequence of letters A, B, ..

out = (
    df.groupby(["Band", grp1, grp2],
               dropna=False, as_index=False, sort=False)["ID"]
        .agg(",".join)[df.columns]
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

         ID  Band
0   A11,A18  1800
1   B11,B18  1800
2       B21  2400
3   C11,C18  1800
4         2  2100
5         3  2100
6     A1,A2  2100
7       A16  2300
8   A11,A18  1800
9   A26,A27  2600
10        9   800
```

Comment: while executing i am getting  Error as KeyError: 'Band'

Comment: But I don't see your code and ignore how you use mine. I got no error when running this one.

Comment: is there any other option i could get the desired output

Comment: I can't help you if you don't show your code. Also, can you `print(df.columns)` ?

Comment: Can you please add (*to your question/post*) the code you used when the error was triggered ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253944/discussion-between-kranthi-kumar-and-timeless).