# iterate over columns and combine the data in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have dataframe like below contains morethan 10k rows

```
   Column A  Column B  Column C
0       A11      1800         1
1       A18      1800         2
2       B11      1800         3
3       B18      1800         4
4       C11      1800         5
5       C18      1800         6
6        A2      2100         7
7        A3      2100         8
8        A1      2100         9
9        A2      2100        10
10      A11      1800        11
11      A18      1800        12
12      A26      2600        13
13      A27      2600        14
14      2        2400        28
15      3         800        23
16      3         800        24
17      C18      2100        32
18      C43      800         42
19      A11      1800        12
20      A18      1800        98
```

i want output as

```
   Column A     Column B    Column C
0       A11,A18      1800         1
2       B11,B18      1800         3
4       C11,C18      1800         5
6   A2,A3,A1,A2      2100         7
10      A11,A18      1800        11
12      A26,A27      2600        13
14      2            2400        28
15      3            800        23
16      3            800        24
17      C18          2100        32
18      C43          800         42
19      A11,A18      1800        12
```

if column A has numbers then do not combine and keep values as it is in all rows, only combined rows will be deleted.

I have modified data for the numbers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply condition on particular columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76399862/apply-condition-on-particular-columns)

Comment: No it is not working for my data

Comment: Your sample input does not have any row where column A is a number. Please add an example what the expected output is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
# extract letter, group by successive identical letters
s = df['Column A'].str.extract(r'^(\D+)', expand=False)
grouper = s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()

out = (df
   .groupby([grouper, 'Column B'],
           as_index=False, sort=False)
   .agg({'Column A': ','.join, 'Column C': 'first'})
   [df.columns]
)
```

*NB. if the type of the numbers is not string, change the `','.join` function to `lambda x: ','.join(x) if len(x)>1 else x`.*

Output:

```
       Column A  Column B  Column C
0       A11,A18      1800         1
1       B11,B18      1800         3
2       C11,C18      1800         5
3   A2,A3,A1,A2      2100         7
4       A11,A18      1800        11
5       A26,A27      2600        13
6             2      2400        28
7             3       800        23
8             3       800        24
9           C18      2100        32
10          C43       800        42
11      A11,A18      1800        12
```

Comment: @KRANTHIKUMAR please check the updated answer and please comment if you have issues, do not open many questions leaving the others without follow-up

Comment: when i use the above code it is dropping other columns. i want other columns as well

Comment: @KRANTHIKUMAR then you should explain that in the question, one cannot guess what you don't tell us. Please give an example as the method will depend on **how** you want to keep the other columns. Most probable answer, just add the other columns in the `agg`: `.agg({'Column A': ','.join, 'Column C': 'first', 'othercol1': 'first', 'othercol2': 'first'})`

Comment: Thank you so much @mozway i thought i was grouping these columns only so if i put the data people may confuse. Thanks i will keep it noted and will be clear from next time onwards